# How to remove the 'tile' background in the launcher icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

First let me show my launcher :-

[image]

I feel my launcher is made to look ugly by the 'square-tile-thing'(for the lack of a better word) thats behind the icon. I want the icons alone to be viewed(without the tile behind). So are there any ways to remove the 'square-tile-thing' ?

PS:- I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with unity. By 'square-tile-thing' I mean the square that is around each icon. (See the picture above or see your own launcher!)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After I was hacking with some files I get it.

## Best method:-

### 1.To Remove the 'tile'

First of all, make a backup of the contents in `/usr/share/unity/icons`. To do so open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type in the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup_icons
cp /usr/share/unity/icons/* ~/backup_icons
```

Then the files below, present in `/usr/share/unity/icons` are to be opened and edited so that all its contents are removed:

```
launcher_icon_back_54.svg
launcher_icon_back_150.svg 
launcher_icon_edge_54.svg
launcher_icon_edge_150.svg
launcher_icon_glow_62.svg
launcher_icon_glow_200.svg
launcher_icon_selected_back_54.svg
launcher_icon_selected_back_150.svg
launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg
launcher_icon_shadow_200.svg
launcher_icon_shine_54.svg
launcher_icon_shine_150.svg
round_glow_62x62.png
round_shine_54x54.png
```

It might be difficult to open each file separately and edit. To avoid that do the following:-

- Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> . Then type in :-

  ```
  cd /usr/share/unity/icons
  ```
- Now type in :-

  ```
  for i in launcher_icon_back_54.svg launcher_icon_back_150.svg launcher_icon_edge_54.svg launcher_icon_edge_150.svg launcher_icon_glow_62.svg launcher_icon_glow_200.svg launcher_icon_selected_back_54.svg launcher_icon_selected_back_150.svg launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg launcher_icon_shadow_200.svg launcher_icon_shine_54.svg launcher_icon_shine_150.svg round_glow_62x62.png round_shine_54x54.png; do sudo inkscape $i && read -p
  ```

This should open each file one by one for you to edit. All you need to do is just select the image that is shown in Inkscape and delete it. Then Save it and close it. Now you need to press `Enter`(aka `Return`) in the terminal for the next file to open. Repeat the editing, saving,closing and pressing `Enter` process again and do the same till you have edited all the files. Now reboot your PC. **You should have your launcher without the tiles.**

**NOTE:-** I have used Inkscape to edit the files. But if you want to use Gimp(or any other editor) you can do so by just changing the word `inkscape` to `gimp`(or the name of any other editor) in the above command.

### 2.To add the 'tile' back again

For this you just have to copy the backup you created above back into `/usr/share/unity/icons`. For this open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following:

```
cp ~/backup_icons/* /usr/share/unity/icons
```

**You should have your launcher back with tiles now.**

## Alternate method:-

### 1.To Remove the Tiles

First you need to get to your `~/Downloads` folder by the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then download a file by the command:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/n48gz3g0fachi3t/icons.tar.gz
```

The download contains a `icons.tar.gz` file. Then make a backup of the image files at `/usr/share/unity/icons` by doing the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup_icons
cp /usr/share/unity/icons/* ~/backup_icons
```

Then get to `/usr/share/unity`:

```
cd /usr/share/unity
```

Now untar the tar file downloaded into `/usr/share/unity` by the following command:

```
sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/icons.tar.gz
```

**This should get rid of the 'tile'** .

### 2.To add the Tile back again

First you need to get to your ~/Downloads folder by the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then download a file by the command:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/31ory2zycvk5c6x/icons.tar.gz
```

The download contains a `icons.tar.gz` file. Then make a backup of the image files at `/usr/share/unity/icons` by doing the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup_icons_notile
cp /usr/share/unity/icons/* ~/backup_icons_notile
```

Then get to `/usr/share/unity`:

```
cd /usr/share/unity
```

Now untar the tar file downloaded into `/usr/share/unity` by the following command:

```
sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/icons.tar.gz
```

**This should add the 'tile' back**.

PS:- Actually, the download file I have provided above contains the `/usr/share/unity/icons` folder with the above mentioned images edited(in the case of "Removing the tile") and unedited(in the case of "Adding the tile back again"). I had thought of saving you the work of editing the images and so I have provided the download files.

By the way, after removing the 'tile' the launcher is going to look like this.(Note: The trash icon will look funny because of my icon set.)

[image]

**CREDITS** for the "Best Method" goes to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455443/how-to-open-several-image-files-from-command-line-consecutively-for-editing) question.

Comment: The Numix GTK theme make that without removing files, do you know how?

Comment: Btw, I just made using your tutorial and everything works, thanks!

Comment: @euDennis No. AFAIK Numix GTK theme will not do that without editing the files.

Comment: I don't have sure if the GTK theme or the Icons, but it can do that. You can check it just installing the Numix themes.

Comment: @crclayton No...  You just need to restart Unity you can do it by logging out and back in, or press Alt + F2 or open up a terminal and type this code in to restart Unity `unity --replace`.

Comment: @Andrew thanks a lot for your answer; this is exactly what I have been looking for. I would like to learn is it possible to enable the minimize/maximize animation as the default one has?

Comment: @talha06 I don't know what exactly you mean since I don't run Unity any longer.  I switch to Gnome Shell in early 2013.  I think it should be in CCSM, so check there.

Comment: Thank you so much MathCubes, you are the only guy hosting usable icons, accidentally bricked my Unity. Saved my tuckus

Answer (score 8):

There is no easy way to do it, since it's hard coded. But a workaround would be editing the images that form the "tile" as you call it and change them for transparent (empty) images.

You can find them in:

```
/usr/share/unity/icons/
```

[image]

There you'll see a bunch of images for when the icon is normal, pressed, highlighted, etc. Edit them with gimp, for example, and replace the originals. Of course, make backups first.

Comment: You can also replace these images and install a circular icon theme like `numix-circle` for more circularity!

Answer (score 2):

I created a shell script on GitHub to do the task. Please check out the [link](https://github.com/mjsolidarios/unity-flatify-icons). Tested on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I just extracted the images provided by Mark (Link: https://github.com/mjsolidarios/unity-flatify-icons/blob/master/assets/unity-launcher-flat-icons.tar.gz) in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/unity folder (My current theme folder). That's enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Another easy approach: Just install a custom theme.
Here you can find a few themes:
http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html
Some of them remove the "ugly by the 'square-tile-thing'" and look partly like the original Unity theme.

(You can switch themes for example with the Unity tweak tool)

Answer (score 1):

The look and feel of the launcher icons are not directly related to Unity per se, but to the GTK+ theme you have currently selected for Unity, most likely the default theme.

Editing the default system theme is not a good idea since any changes you make are likely to be overwritten by an update. If you choose to go with this approach then consider cloning the current theme and giving it a different name.

Having said that there are already enough themes that don't have the launcher icons underlays.

I got satisfactory results with the [mbuntu theme flavour from noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/mbuntu-y-macbuntu-transformation-pack.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mbuntu-y-ithemes-v5

## optional icons, which go well with the theme 
sudo apt-get install mbuntu-y-icons-v5
```

Next, install [Ubuntu Tweak](https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak) which is needed in order to switch the themes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Now launch Ubuntu Tweak, click <kbd>Tweaks</kbd> -> <kbd>Theme</kbd>, and select **MBuntu-Y-Unity** under ***Gtk theme*** and ***Window theme***. Optionally select the Mbuntu icon theme.

Here is how the final result might look like:

[image]