# Why doesn't my dock have the icons of my icon theme?

Tags: unity, 14.04, cairo-dock, icon-themes

I just downloaded Numix circle icon theme. I applied that theme from Unity tweak tool. Now my launcher and Nautilus has the theme I applied but Cairo dock doesn't. Why is it so and how to change my dock to get that theme?

PS :- I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. I have also made some edits in my launcher as suggested in the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons).

Comment: Cairo Dock has it's own themes. Either  ask the author of the theme to make a theme for cairo dock or do it yourself.

Comment: @xangua Hmm...Probably you must elaborate on this and post this as an answer.

Comment: @xangua Well no need! Check out my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that it was quite simple to have the Numix Circle icon theme in Cairo Dock actually ! I will show how to do it below.

- Right click on any icon in the dock. Select `Cairo-Dock > Configure` as shown below:

---

[image]

---

- Now in the Cairo-Dock configuration window select the `Appearance` tab as shown below:

---

[image]

---

- Now in the `Appearance` tab after the option `Choose a theme of icons` select your icon theme(Its Numix Circle in my case) as shown below:

---

[image]

---

and voila! You have got your icon theme in Cairo Dock!