# How to open several image files from command line, consecutively, for editing?

Tags: command-line, bash

Lets say I have three image files to edit. Consider all the files are in `~/Pictures`. Let name of the first file be `1.svg`, name of the second file be `2.svg` and name of the third file be `3.svg` .I have Inkscape editor. Now, I want a bash script to be executed so that the following must happen:

1. First `1.svg` must open for me to edit.
2. After editing, when I close that file, automatically `2.svg` must open for me to edit.
3. Now when I complete editing `2.svg`, I want `3.svg` to open for editing.
4. Now after editing `3.svg` the script must end by closing GIMP.

PS:- If you are wondering if this is home work, it is not! See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons) . You will notice that I have to edit images there. To make that answer better I need help here. So please help. Also *I AM A COMPLETE BEGINNER*. I don't know anything about bash. So **explain your answer as elaborately as possible**. Also you might consider giving an answer with GIMP editor to edit .jpg files . It might be useful for others. By the way, I am using 14.04 LTS . Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :- The above linked answer was edited according to the accepted answer below.

Comment: Why don't you want to open them all at the same time?

Comment: @Nattgew Well that would be a mess if I have a lot of files. Did you see the "Alternate method" mentioned in Andrew's answer in the link I provided?

Comment: @Nattgew Ok.. I edited the answer there and it aint approved there still.. Please wait for sometime till approval..

Comment: `for i in 1.jpeg 2.jpeg 3.jpg; do gimp $i; done`? This will relaunch gimp every time, tough. If you want to do that thing without closing gimp you should probably use a gimp script (which I do not grok at all). I still think that opening them as tabs as @Nattgew says is the best option... (BTW,  in your linked answer, `.svg` files are better not edited by GIMP; they are vector shapes, you should use f.e. Inkscape).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Rmano says, you can simply do a `for` loop in the terminal:

```
for i in 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg; do gimp $i; done
```

Either run this in the directory where the files are, or each file should have the rest of the path to it. You can put as many files as you want in there.

GIMP will open the file, you edit it, and then close GIMP. Once GIMP closes, the `for` loop continues and opens the next file in the list.

If you don't want to close GIMP every time, you can try adding a `read -p`:

```
for i in 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg; do gimp $i && read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."; done
```

Once you finish editing a file, you should be able to press Enter in the terminal and the next file should open in GIMP, without having to close GIMP.

This is the simplest way I could think of, it may get complicated trying to detect when GIMP closes a file.

**Note for your case**

Most of the files are SVG files, as Rmano pointed out. So list all of your SVG files and replace `gimp` with `inkscape`. The PNG files will be fine with `gimp`.

Comment: Right.. BTW i can add any number of files right? Not just three...Also I should be in the ~/Pictures folder for this to run or can I mention the path there?

Comment: @Venki You will need to be in the `~/Pictures` directory, yes. and you can just replace `gimp` with whatever editor you want to use.

Comment: @Nattgew Your method works fine! But totally changing the subject it says it couldn't save my file..any help with that?

Comment: @Nattgew I ran Seth's answer below as a bash script(I mean i saved it as a .sh file and ran it) and tried saving my edits in it and it worked just fine(though it throws other insignificant errors)..

Comment: @Venki It probably couldn't save the file because you aren't using `sudo` privileges. You need to use `sudo` because you're editing files in `/usr`. IMO this answer is still better than mine.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, even though the answer by Giles and Seth work perfectly. This is because, this answer has a slight edge over the other two answers in that I can terminate the process easily in the middle. That is to say, if I am in 2.svg and I have a sudden change of mind to quit there without opening 3.jpg , I can do that if I don't press enter in the terminal and just close the terminal, after closing 2.jpg.

Answer (score 7):

The following command [opens the files in the default associated application](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/edit.1.html):

```
edit 1.svg 2.svg 3.svg
```

If you want to open all the `.svg` files in alphabetical order, you can use the `*` wildcard:

```
edit *.svg
```

`*` stands for any sequence of characters, so you can use it in other ways; for example, to successively open the `.svg` files whose name contains `wibble`:

```
edit *wibble*.svg
```

Other wildcards exist if you want to select files based on finer-grained patterns.

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: I would use `find -exec` if I want to selectively open some of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *
do
    if [ -d "$i"  ]
     then
        continue
    else
        inkscape "$i"

    fi
done
```

I tested it on my Pictures directory and it seemed to work.

I don't entirely understand the first line yet, but it is there to help make sure my `*` works. The `for` loop then loops through everything in the current directory one at a time. If it isn't a directory it opens it in Inkscape for editing.

When you're done editing and close inkscape the next image will open until there are no more images.

---

For your specific case (after reading the linked question) this might work better. Remember to `cd` to `/usr/share/unity/icons` and then run this:

```
for i in file1.svg file2.svg file3.svg
do
    if [ -d "$i"  ]
     then
        continue
    else
        inkscape "$i"

    fi
done
```

replacing `file1.svg file2.svg file3.svg` with a list of the files you want to edit.

Comment: I think `nullglob` means it won't try to iterate on a literal `*` if it matches nothing else?

Comment: @Nattgew That is correct, after looking into it more.

Comment: @Seth I put your answer in gedit saved it as a .sh file and ran it ... it worked like a dream!!!! But there are a few errors ... here is the .sh file I saved: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7332714/ and here is the terminal message that shows up : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7332719/ Probably there is something wrong with the cd command I added in my bash script? Or is this how your answer should run ?

Comment: @Venki I probably don't need the double brackets. I've removed them. You might also need to use `sudo inkscape` since you're editing files in /usr.

Comment: @Venki the errors were because you were using `/bin/sh` (which is `dash` on Ubuntu systems) and not `bash`. The `[[ ]]` test is not available in `dash`. Just change your first line (the shebang) to `#!/bin/bash` or, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and Seth's first version will work fine.