# Remove/Close sidebar when using Cairo-Dock

Tags: launcher, cairo-dock

How do I close the top bar and the left side bar now that I am using Cairo-Dock as my primary access point for everything? Please help if you can. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, even though you have Cairo dock, you should not remove the launcher or the Global menu bar. You can use several app indicators in your Global menu bar(See  [here]http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available). Though even I have cairo dock, if I have to show off to my friends, I show them my beautiful launcher! If you want to make your launcher more beautiful see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons). Thought it would be right to suggest this, though it won't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt` should remove the status bar.
([Reference](http://lifehacker.com/5887462/how-to-disable-ubuntus-annoying-global-menu-bar))

Go to system settings, Appearance, Click on the Behaviour tab, then Auto hide the launcher should be on.
You probably want Top left corner, and the slider down as low as possible.

Comment: I did the terminal thing and got this.Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package appmenu-qt is not installed, so not removed
Package appmenu-gtk is not installed, so not removed
Package appmenu-gtk3 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Hmm, try logging out and in again, has it gone?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply. It's still there. I did do the hide until click over thing but I want it gone completly