# How to hide unity launcher border line

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, 15.10

I'm on 14.04. I have my launcher on full transparency and I've [hidden the containing boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons), and to complete the picture and have the icons completely hovering, it'd be nice to hide the border line or change the colour. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with 15.10.

Comment: @Ivan after over a year of inactivity, this question suddenly got a lot of [attention in November](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4wDPG.png). Can you shed some light on what happened to bring you here?

Comment: too bad that unity developers have apparently opted for keeping this hard-coded :-( maybe filing a bug (e.g. 1px away from full transparency) in launchpad attracting a large number of supporters might help persuade them to implement it in the same way as button backgrounds, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not configurable.
If you go to the Unity Plugin options under Compiz Config Manager, you will not see any option regarding to that separation line.

An option should be added to the Compiz plugin in order to control that. Otherwise, download the code, modify it and compile your own Unity package without the line :-/