# Having problems removing unity background tiles

Tags: unity

I'm trying to remove the 'tile background' in the launcher icons following
[this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons), but I keep getting this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `launcher_icon_edge_54.svg'.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and wondering if I am doing something wrong or it's different with older releases. Also I'm using the Moka icon pack and grey ambiance theme.

```
tyler@Afteramth:~$ cd /usr/share/unity/icons
tyler@Afteramth:/usr/share/unity/icons$ for i in launcher_icon_back_54.svg launcher_icon_back_150.svg launcher_icon_edge_54.svg   
>launcher_icon_edge_150.svg launcher_icon_glow_62.svg launcher_icon_glow_200.svg`
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `launcher_icon_edge_150.svg'
tyler@Afteramth:/usr/share/unity/icons$
```

This is what I input to the terminal and what it returns when I try to follow the instructions in the question I've linked.

Comment: Please describe as precisely as possible, under which circumstances this error message occurs. I suspect it is after the entry of a particular command. Can you please provide this command, so we can even begin to help you?

Comment: probably you did a copy-and-paste into terminal, and terminal recognized some illegal characters. Remove `single quotes` or `back ticks` and type them from keyboard.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem.  I tried typing them in by hand and removing the characters you had said to and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing invalid bash in the terminal, and it is unable to parse it.

As for the answer in your linked question, it is not a particularly good suggestion to follow. Any changes you make there will be overridden when an update for unity is installed.

Comment: Is there a better way? Or should i just leave it alone? Also thanks fir the edit I'm still new here.

Comment: I'd just leave it alone. It's not worth the hassle of having to keep replacing them every time an update comes along. It also won't result in the app icons themselves being larger.