# Change Unity Launcher Style

Tags: unity, launcher

I want to change my launcher to look like the one Kali Linux uses, as shown in the image:

[image: Kali Linux Launcher Image]

Is that possible ?

Comment: Kali uses GNOME desktop, so you could switch to that instead of default Unity environment.  That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu GNOME, which, like Kali, uses the GNOME3 desktop environment, or more simply install GNOME3 on your current system. Other than that, probably the best you can do is to remove the tile background from the launcher icons, using [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450539/how-to-remove-the-tile-background-in-the-launcher-icons).